# Table formatting based on cell content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have a table with text in left-most column and numbers in all other columns. How can I color the cells based on the number in them? I want to set the background-color = "red" for negative number and ignore the column with text in it and also ignore the cells with positive numbers in them.

Below is a code that I picked up from another question and modified a little bit but it does not seem to work.

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];
    var currentVal = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
    if(currentVal.toFixed){
        if (currentVal <0)
            node.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // -ive number
    } else{
        // do nothing, the cell has text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the number:

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];
    var currentVal = parseFloat(node.childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
    if(currentVal!=NaN){
        if (currentVal <0)
            node.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } 
}
```

Or better with jQuery & css:

Script:

```
$("td").filter(function(c){
    var num=parseFloat(this.innerText);
    return num!=NaN && num < 0;
}).addClass("neg");
```

or

```
$("td:contains('-')").addClass("neg");
```

CSS:

```
.neg{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing inside the style for td.number, like this => td.number { text-align:right; /* format based on actual content*/}

Comment: What do you mean? using node.class?

Comment: Could I define a new class like td.number and inside it test for value and then format accordingly? Something like <style> td.number{if value<0 background-color:"red"} </style>

Comment: I added other possible solutions